# Erro de conversão de retorno JSON para Classe JAVA

Tags: php, java, json, api, classes

Tenho uma **classe java**

```
public class PRODUTO extends SugarRecord implements Parcelable {

  private float id_pro;

  public PRODUTO(float id_pro){
    this.id_pro = id_pro;
  }

  public float getId_pro() {
    return id_pro;
  }
  public void setId_pro(float id_pro) {
    this.id_pro = id_pro;
  }
  // PARCELABLE
  public PRODUTO(Parcel parcel) {
    setId_pro(parcel.readFloat());
  }
  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }
  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeFloat(getId_pro());
  }
  ...
}
```

Uma **API php** que me retorna um **JSON** da minha base **mysql**, nele vem o **id_pro**, por exemplo: 257895

Porem sempre add **automaticamente** um **".0"** no final da variável DEPOIS DE ATRIBUIR A CLASSE, ficando assim: 257895.0

Já verifiquei os dados de retorno, ele vem certo do JSON, mas na hora de atribuir a classe fica assim, na base  mysql tenho um campo **bigint** que já mudei para **float** também para testar e não deu. Porém quando uso String na classe para o **id_pro**, recebe corretamente 257895, mas queria trabalhar direto no formato do objeto.

Uso um **HttpURLConnection** para a requisição.

Alguém tem uma ideia do que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `float` no Java representa um número de vírgula flutuante com precisão de 32 bits pelo sempre que escrever o número, a menos que esteja a fazer algo como um `Console.WriteLine()` com uma *format string*, ele vai sempre escrever o `.0` caso não tenha casas decimais para indicar que realmente não tem casas decimais.

A solução será utilizar um tipo de dados que represente um número inteiro porque na verdade o ID é *sempre* um número inteiro e para iusso pode usar quer o `int` quer o `long`  - ou os seus wrappers, `Int` e `Long`. Tenha apenas em atenção que em Java o `int` utiliza 32 bits e o `long` utiliza 64, por isso o `long` apesar de gastar mais memória - fácil perceber porque representa o dobro dos bits de um `int` - também representa muitos, muitos mais números:

```
 int | -2^31 a +2^31 -1 |             -2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647
long | -2^63 a +2^63 -1 | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 a 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

---

**Recursos úteis**

- [Tipos de Dados Primitivos (*em Inglês*)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

---

> **Fun fact**: com um `long`, se a sua função fizer um incremento a cada nano segundo, iria demorar 292 anos a dar overflow (**!!!**) [*fonte*](https://www.google.pt/search?q=9%2C223%2C372%2C036%2C854%2C775%2C807%20nanoseconds%20in%20years)

Comment: Opa, valeu Tiago, foi isto mesmo, como long ele não faz, valeu!